How do I make a telegram bot react to a message in JavaScript
I'm trying to make my telegram bot react to the media or message the users sends
Tried this method but it didn't work . I would appreciate it if anyone could show me another method to do this using Javascript. Thanks .
async function sendReaction(chatId, messageId, emoji) {
    const url = `${TELEGRAM_API_URL}/sendMessage`;
    const params = {
        chat_id: chatId,
        text: emoji,
        reply_to_message_id: messageId,
    };
    try {
        const response = await axios.post(url, params);
        console.log('Reaction sent successfully:', response.data);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error sending reaction:', error.response ? error.response.data : error.message);
    }
}

async function handleMediaMessage(message) {
    const chatId = message.chat.id;
    const messageId = message.message_id;
    const mediaFileId = message.photo
        ? message.photo[message.photo.length - 1].file_id
        : message.video
        ? message.video.file_id
        : null;
    if (mediaFileId) {
        await sendReaction(chatId, messageId, '');
        const fileUrl = await getFileUrl(mediaFileId);
        const results = await fetchTraceMoeResults(fileUrl);
        console.log('Results:', results);
    }
}

